# Python: Sort list of lists by not one, but two criteria

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I have a Python sorting problem which is similar to other problems I found on stackoverflow, but not quite the same. Let me show you, maybe someone may help:

Assume that we have a list of lists which may look like this:

`p = [[6, 'k'], [5, 'l'], [2, 'p'], [2, 'd'], [5, 'k']]`

I want to sort this by two (!) criteria. Sorting it by one criterion is rather easy and straightforward. Let's assume I want to first sort it by the first item of each list. I could implement this as such:

`sorted_p = sorted(p, key=lambda x:int(x[0]))`

So far so good. I would get the following sorted_p:

`[[2,'p'], [2, 'd'], [5, 'l'], [5, 'k'], [6, 'k']]`

Now the real trouble starts: I want that in every case where there are multiple occurrences of the first item (e.g. we have two tuples starting with 2 and two tuples starting with 5) that these tuples are then sorted by the second item of the tuple. So what I would like to get as a result would be

`[[2,'d'], [2, 'p'], [5, 'k'], [5, 'l'], [6, 'k']]`

Has anyone an idea how I can do that?

Thanks for every hint!

Comment: quick and dirty could be `key=lambda x: 1000 * x[0] + ord( x[1] )`

Comment: ...or look [here](http://www.lleess.com/2013/08/python-sort-list-by-multiple-attributes.html)

Comment: Sorry I should have explained that these are just example values. It might well be that the first items are letters or sentences and the second items floats or something else. So I need a rather general approach to the problem instead of a quick and dirty one. But thanks anyway

Comment: Hey, the link looks promising!! I'll dive into it after lunch :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python automatically sorts by more than 1 criteria if you pass it a tuple. In your case it would be:

```
p = [[6, 'k'], [5, 'l'], [2, 'p'], [2, 'd'], [5, 'k']]
sorted_p = sorted(p, key=lambda x:(int(x[0]),x[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Advay168. This worked perfectly well and I'm glad I learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great. Just adding another answer without using the built-in sort in case of customizations it can be extended.

```
def custom_bubble_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        for j in range(len(arr)-i-1):
            if arr[j][0] > arr[j+1][0]:
                temp = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[j+1]
                arr[j+1] = temp
            elif arr[j][0] == arr[j+1][0] and ord(arr[j][1]) > ord(arr[j+1][1]):
                    temp = arr[j]
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1]
                    arr[j+1] = temp
    return arr

print(custom_bubble_sort([[6, 'k'], [5, 'l'], [2, 'p'], [2, 'd'], [5, 'k']]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this version using `operator.itemgetter` reads better than the `lambda` version:

```
import operator
p = [[6, 'k'], [5, 'l'], [2, 'p'], [2, 'd'], [5, 'k']]
sorted_p = sorted(p, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))
```